# Wix - check if environment variable is exist and then it's value

Tags: wix

On our setup, I need to check if some environment variable is exist, and the check if it's set to 1 or 0.

```
<?ifdef $(env.Enable_LBA) ?>
    <?if $(env.Enable_LBA) = 1?>
           Do things
    <?endif ?>
<?endif ?>
```

for some reason, this doesn't work. if I leave only the  statements, the build fail if the env. variable isn't define. when it's like the above, it doesn't work even after setting Enable_LBA=1

Comment: If your behavior for empty and undefined environment variable are identical, you may be able to skip the outer check.

Comment: Do you already know to check the Value of an envirenment variable ??

Comment: The code in the question is actualy working